# floating point arithmetic with functions

Tags: bash, function, math, floating-point, sh

What these functions do is they curl a json file and parse it, whose output is a number.

```
function func() {
curl -Ss -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' url.com/A?limit=2 | jq -r '. 
[] | .[] | .blah'
}
function func2() {
curl -Ss -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' url.com/B2?limit=2 | jq -r '. 
[] | .[] | .blah'
}
function func3() {
curl -Ss -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' url.com/C3?limit=2 | jq -r '. 
[] | .[] | .blah'
} 

function example() { 
"(($(func) * $(func2) * $(func3)))" | bc -l
}
#result is it echoing the numbers, but not actually doing the math.
#echoing .072*.027 in bc, but no math.
```

So what I'm trying to do is do floating point arithmetic through bash, this is going to be referenced through another function. The only difference is this is with functions. Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic which is solved through bc.

Example Function numeric output:

```
#func output
0.072854 #A
0.072855 #B
0.072828 #C
0.072827 #D

#func2 output
0.027873 #A
0.027884 #B
0.027848 #C
0.027847 #D

#func3 output
0.383170 #A
0.383215 #B
0.381858 #C
0.381857 #D
```

How it works, A * A * A = output1, B * B * B = output2, C * C * C = ouput3

What I've Tried:

```
function blah() {
echo $((func*func2*func3)) | bc -l
}
#result is "0"

echo "$(func) * $(func2) * $(func3)" | bc -l
#result is:
.072965
.072966
.072925
.002030350008
.027856
.027827
.010633768950
.382371
.380995
.380977
```

Comment: Can you provide the `JSON` you are using to get that output, and are there always the same number of items output each time?

Comment: yes, there is always the same number of items output

Comment: If there is the option of piping the output of all three `curl`s to `jq`, it can do floating-point math as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll want your function to be like this:

```
echo "$(func) * $(func2) * $(func3)" | bc -l
```

**EDIT**: Since you have multiple values that are output you could put them into arrays, then loop through them and multiply the values:

```
example() {
  a=($(func1))
  b=($(func2))
  c=($(func3))

  for i in {0..3} # set to number of values returned
    do 
      echo "${a[i]} * ${b[i]} * ${c[i]}" | bc -l
    done
}
```

Based on your values the output should be:

```
.000778087816708140
.000778496988156300
.000774451610799552
.000774411139231933
```

If your `func`'s return a value then using `echo` with `bc` with them should be sufficient.

Comment: Weird thing is it places it in bc but doesn't multiply it like it should, anyway i've changed the function output to a more accurate representation.

Comment: About the output values you are showing, are they all together like that (eg. 4 values each at a time?). If you can provide what the formula should be (what exactly needs to be multiplied) and what the end result should be that would help.